# I have to fetch 500K rows from the database and write that data into the file , Means perform the I/O operation

Tags: java, performance, file-io

I have to fetch 500K rows from the database and write that data into the file , Means perform the I/O operation . I have done for two steps .

1. Write each row one by one into the file .
2. Make the chunk of those rows .Append those rows in StringBuffer and then print it . This one will be better but is there any way that File I/O can make the buffer on it's own without using StringBuffer . As this String Buffer is taking more time (Internally it use Arrays.copyOf)

Please suggest me on this 
Please find the code attached with this

```
public void fetchDataWithChunkSpace(Connection con)throws Exception
        {
            String query ="select * from lis.testxml  ";
            long startTime=new Date().getMinutes();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("c:\\test_chunkSpace.xml"));
            pw.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String t=null; 
            long count =0;
            while(rs.next())
            {   count++;
                t = rs.getString("xmltest");
                sb = sb.append(t);
                if(count%100==0)
                {
                 pw.write(sb.toString());
                 sb = new StringBuffer();
                 System.out.println(count);
                }
            }
            pw.write("\n");
            pw.write("</EndTag>");
            pw.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            long endTime=new Date().getMinutes();
            System.out.println("chunkSpace  ---> " + (endTime-startTime));
        }
```

Comment: So what is your problem? And what is your question?

Comment: Please show the code of how you write to the File. File I/O is usually done in buffered mode.

Comment: Maybe you should show some code. You could directly write to the OutputStream instead of buffering in a StringBuffer, you could use StringBuilder, initialize the Buffer/Builder with an expected size (Integer argument in constructor)... there are several options. What exactly is your problem, is it too slow?

Comment: It is most like that reading from the database is your bottle neck.  How you write the data to a file is less likely to be important.  You should be able to write to a file up to 90 MB/s of text, depending on the speed of your drive. BTW I would use StringBuilder as suggested in StringBuffer's Javadoc.

Comment: I have added the comment and also updated code , Can u please let me know now ? My code is not indented still Sorry for this

Comment: Why is it not indented? Is it in this form in your editor? Or is it because you cannot be bothered to present it in a decipherable form?

Comment: Is this code not readable to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [BufferedOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) or [BufferedWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

Also consider that StringBuffer is thread-safe class with synchronyzed methods unlike StringBuilder.

Update.
Try this code:

```
Writer pw = new BufferedWriter(new PrintWriter(new File("c:\\test_chunkSpace.xml")));
pw.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
String t;
while (rs.next()) {
    t = rs.getString("xmltest");
    pw.write(t);
}
```

Comment: I have done one more analysis with RandomAccessFile that give me better performance with this scenario .

Answer (score 2):

[BufferedWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)

Comment: +1: That is what I would do, even if the explanation is a bit short. ;)

Comment: @gaurav, Can you try using a BufferedWriter instead of a StringBuffer?

Comment: IMHO BufferedWriter and StringBuffer can be used together, StringBuffer provides better performance and memory usage when working woth strings, while BufferedWriter improves I/O by buffering during writing to a File / FileWriter e.g.

Comment: BufferWriter provides all the advantages of StringBuffer (but is not synchronized) Using both is likely to just duplicate effort.

Comment: Depends what you want to do - both have append() but that make BufferedWriter a replacement for StringBuffer. If you are sure that thread-safety is not an issue, you can use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer, but honestly I do not know how big the performance boost will be.

Comment: Its pretty rare that you want to write to a single file from multiple threads and StringBuffer is all you need. i.e. you don't care what order the append()s are performed.  I was thinking of the duplicated developer effort. ;)

Comment: I have done one more analysis with RandomAccessFile that give me better performance with this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You must use an XML library for producing XML. Otherwise you won't produce valid XML and it will be your fault. You should make maximal use of output buffering to speed the writing process, however I agree with the other posters that you are most probably input-bound on the database, rather than there being much scope for improving your actual code.